# Changing symbology orientation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a project based on data from a water company, but the arrow heads are all pointing in the wrong direction to indicate the direction of flow.
Basically I need to turn all the SYMBOLROTA values to negatives. How can I change all the values of a set of features to become minus - it might be a search function of a script or something?

Better than that would be to be able to change the type of rotation (like you can do in AutoCAD) to be anti-clockwise rather than clockwise. I haven't been able to find out how to do that but that would be the easiest?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of you symbology and its settings.

Answer (score 4):

We worked it out - in the attributes table there's a Field Calculator where you can do various calculations based on the data.
We selected all the data points and then opened the Field Calculator and updated the existing field (tickbox near top right) and applied the simple calc  `"SYMBOLROTA" * -1` which just multiplies all the values in the `SYMBOLROTA` column and puts the answers back in the `SYMBOLROTA` column replacing the original values.